# Cakephp randomly drops session

Tags: session, cakephp, sessionid

Recently I moved my cakephp site from a hosting service to an other. The page was working like a charm, but now I'm having the issue, that my sessions randomly drop.
I'm on a shared hosting service, so I changed cake's session defaults from php to cake, now my sessions are saved to my tmp/sessions folder. (but it wasn't working with php either)

Followed my session's way with Firebug:

1. When i log into the page, i have a Sessionid, and in the tmp/sessions folder i have the corresponding sess_{sessionid} file too.
2. After a few clicks on some pages (totally random) my sessionid changes and i'm "logged out".
   The session file with which i've logged in, remained in the directory.

My session settings in core.php right now:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cake'
));
```

I'm using the 2.3.8 version of Cake.

---

**Update:**

Finally i found the problem thanks to Nick. I checked the Cakephp error files, and found out that i only got logged out, when i visited a page containing an element, which was not on the server ( eg a picture was missing). So i went to Firebug, and check what the Net tab says. On the new Host service i got a 404 Not Found response AND a new session id set in the response, whilst on the other servers i tested the page, i simply got a 404 Not Found. If i randomly generate links to not existing files like (`domain/test.jpg`) i get the same results.

Comment: This looks like a classic issue with php cookie expiring before the session. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304390/cakephp-session-updates-but-cookie-expiry-doesnt

Comment: unfortunately not, the expiration of the session cookie is set to a few hours (and that is correcty set, checked in firebug), but i'm logged out within a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings, in Firefox you can install the web develop extension, then you can view your cookie to see if it is all set correct.

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'php',
'cookie' => 'yourdomain',
'timeout' => 44640,
));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still somethings is not right. Now my cookie is renamed, and it expires in november, but somehow i still get logged out, and get a new session id

Comment: Try another browser or from another machine. Firebug sometimes messes up headers in a way that it looks that the request is coming from another browser.

Comment: That's a good start, at least it is not the cookie what expires, but it seems to be more related to your login and swapping to other pages, I suppose you use the correct way to set and get your data between the swapping? Also are you sure it is only because you swapped hosting? have you tried to run your program in a Xammp or Wammp environment, just to make sure it is your hoster? which seems weird because if you use cakephp to store your cookie it is not going to the shared /tmp folder for all shared hosting customers.

Comment: Have you considered to update to the version 2.3.10? Oh, perhaps even more important,, when you swapped hosting, did you get a newer PHP version? check your error_log files [also related to update to v2.3.10]

Comment: Chrome shows the same sympthoms.
I developed the page in Xampp environment, then tested it on a shared hosting service, and after that i bought a domain at an other hosting service, and only there have problems.
The php versions i tested the page on: 5.3.8, 5.3.23, and now : 5.3.27-pl0-gentoo.
Tomorrow i'll try to update to 2.4.1, and tell you how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Check any components that you are using for whitespace (usually at the end of the file).

I came across this recently whilst helping a client with their existing CakePHP site, when logged in one particular page that called a component was killing $this->Session->read(‘Auth’).

There is a  CakePHP shell that you can use to [find whitespace](http://bin.cakephp.org/saved/33005).